# Jenkins generated ipa couldnt install on iPhone (iOS 9 + XCode 7.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jenkins, xcode7

I am trying to implement Jenkins CI to generate build for iOS. I have latest Xcode 7.1 installed and ipa is getting generated without error. While trying to install the ipa through download link I am getting an error saying "Cannot install this time". Also I tried to install the same through iTunes, but getting an error saying "1 item could not be synced" and iTunes showing an error saying "The app "xxxxx" was not installed on the iPhone "xxxxxx" because an unknown error occurred (0xE8000005)".

Code signing certificate & provisioning profiles are proper and I am able to install the ipa generated from XCode.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Using Jenkins 2.5 and Xcode 7.3.1. Jenkins successfully build iOS app packaged the ipa, but the ipa did not install on the iPhone neither with iTunes nor when downloaded from TestFairy. Getting the same error "The app "xxxxx" was not installed on the iPhone "xxxxxx" because an unknown error occurred (0xE8000005)".

In the Jenkins logs I noticed following:

```
22:03:10 ### Checking original app
22:03:10 + /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/app-ios-build-job/build/MyAppProd.app
22:03:10 Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/app-ios-build-job/build/MyAppProd.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
22:03:10 file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/app-ios-build-job/build/MyAppProd.app/MyAppProd.app
22:03:10 ]
22:03:10 Codesign check fails : /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/app-ios-build-job/build/MyAppProd.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
22:03:10 file added: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/app-ios-build-job/build/MyAppProd.app/MyAppProd.app
22:03:10 
22:03:10 Done checking the original app
```

On further search found the answer posted by bladebunny at https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/782

Issue turned out to be duplicate package commands on Jenkins that resulted in the app being signed twice -- and then causing install to fail. Solution was to change Jenkins Xcode plugin settings. Under the 'General Build Settings' - we found you can't check both "Generate Archive" and "Pack application and build .ipa?" settings. The plugin issues log seems to suggest the former setting is being deprecated. We use the latter setting and are now able to successfully deploy the app with our custom dynamic framework.

The above fix worked for me.